# Upload Image with Guzzle 7

Tags: php, guzzle

I'm trying to upload an image using guzzlehttp/guzzle v7.2. The curl command works correctly as:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'http://31.207.77.245/services/update?id=' . $s2jsonResponse->hits[0]->id,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('Filedata'=> new CURLFILE($hit->metadata->path)),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $authToken
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
```

while when using guzzle:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

$headers = [];
$headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' . $authToken;

$request = $client->request('POST', 'http://31.207.77.245/services/update?id=' . $s2jsonResponse->hits[0]->id,
    ['multipart' =>[
        [
            'name'     => 'Filedata',
            'contents' => fopen($hit->metadata->filename, 'rb'),
            'headers'  => $headers
        ]
    ]]);

$urequest->getBody();
```

it fails with the error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL error 55: Send failure: Broken pipe (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for http://31.207.77.245/services/update?id=B9l8TjX1a0A93YMSF6IDoH in /Users/augusto/Documents/assets/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php:211
```

Comment: Move the headers array outside of the multipart.  Headers are part of the request, not the multipart data you are sending.  `'POST', 'http:...', ['headers' => [$headers], ['multipart' =>`

Comment: The error is gone but the API is not accepting the parameters sent on the multipart...

Comment: What response are you getting?  Do you have  a try..catch block around the code?  Is there an exception?

Comment: The API responds with the message: "No 'metadata' or '<fieldName>' parameters specified".

Answer (score 1):

It worked as:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

$headers = [];
$headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' . $authToken;

$request = $client->request('POST', 'http://31.207.77.245/services/update?id=' . $s2jsonResponse->hits[0]->id, [
    'headers' => $headers,
    'multipart' => [
        [
            'name'     => 'Filedata',
            'contents' => fopen($hit->metadata->filename, 'rb')
        ]
    ]]);

$urequest->getBody();
```